# In Apache ActiveMQ Artemis, how can I force Stomp messages to be text instead of binary?

Tags: websocket, stomp, activemq-artemis

We have just switched to **Apache ActiveMQ Artemis**, enabling the **Stomp server** for Javascript WebSocket subscriptions, and everything is working fine, but we're receiving messages as "kind of" binary data.

Frames are marked as `isBinaryBody: true` and I can also spot a companion `binaryBody` property.

I understand that this is the default behaviour in Apache ActiveMQ Artemis, but is there any way to disable/configure this and make it work with text only messages?

Comment: Where are you seeing the `isBinaryBody: true` exactly? Is it part of the actual STOMP [`MESSAGE`](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.2.html#MESSAGE) frame or part of something specifically related to WebSockets? Also, when you _send_ the `MESSAGE` frame is that also binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently ActiveMQ Artemis is hard-coded to encode WebSocket frames as binary. There is no way to configure the broker to do it differently. However, I have opened [ARTEMIS-4294](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4294) and sent/merged a PR for this functionality. It will be available in 2.29.0, and you can set `webSocketEncoderType=text` on the `stomp` `acceptor`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reactivity to this feature request. I hope it can hit production as soon as possible. Thank you.